Remove padding or margin in grid column space using tailwind css
I am creating one responsive design where i need to use three column inside header for all the device resolution.
I have started developing mobile first responsive header, In below code i am escaping the tablet resolution. For explanation used only mobile and laptop resolution.
<div class="m-0 grid grid-cols-12 gap-1">
  <div class="rounded-lg col-span-2 lg:col-span-1">backIcon</div>
  <div class="rounded-lg shadow col-span-8 lg:col-span-10">Hello World</div>
  <div class="rounded-lg col-span-2 bg-purple-500 shadow lg:col-span-1">Icon</div>
</div>

This code i used in tailwind Play Area
Above code works fine for mobile, But when i check for laptop screen, I found like the first column have more space which i need to decrease, So that the middle column content should be near to the first column content.
Need help.

What width are you expecting for each column on mobile and desktop? Right now you're splitting 2/8/2 below lg and 1/10/1 on lg and above. If you want a fixed width for the first and last columns you can use a flex row instead which would be simpler.

So you are suggesting to use lg:flex for the above code?

That depends on what width you want for each column on each breakpoint. It's not clear from the question.

e.g: for first div which have col-span-2 with lg:col-span-1, In this i have one back icon but when i inspect this element i found like the column width has taken more space than icon. Due to it the next column content is little far to the first column div. I need here for the first div column should contain only that space based on their content.

I think you want to use flex then. Something like this: https://play.tailwindcss.com/SogNmYz1aW. The left and right columns will use as much space as their content requires and the middle one will expand to take the rest.

This link is fine, But i have one more div same like hello world div, Which i need to be show as column, Just down of the Hello world div. I will update my question, Oh! since i am new user, I don't have option to edit the question. Here is one more div in below:Hello World Details

I have got one solution for this:
We can use grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 1fr auto; css, And in tailwind it should be like : grid-cols-[auto_1fr_auto]
using this has removed the extra space taken in the each column of the grid and working as expected.

Try this
<div class="m-0 grid grid-cols-12 gap-1 lg:gap-0">
  <div class="rounded-lg col-span-2 lg:col-span-1">backIcon</div>
  <div class="rounded-lg shadow col-span-8 lg:col-span-10">Hello World</div>
  <div class="rounded-lg col-span-2 bg-purple-500 shadow lg:col-span-1">Icon</div>
</div>


In your suggested code, You have just added lg:gap-0, Except this all the code is as it it as i mention above and it did not change anything in the layout as i mentioned.
